# Is there any way to download subtitles from ARD Mediathek?

Tags: learning, resource

I watch a lot of ARD dramas to improve my listening comprehension, and I also use the dialogues to create cards for my Anki collection.

Currently I do all this manually, i.e. when I find something worth learning, I type it all up by hand.

I was wondering if there is a way to download the SRT files directly and then copy and paste what I want into my Anki cards. I can do this with Netflix using a Chrome extension.

Has anyone done anything like this?

Comment: 57,50€? That seems like 40€ too much.

Comment: Some programs (e.g.RBB or BR)  provide .srt files for download, it's a bit tricky to find these though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about German language. It is a question about a broadcast company.

Comment: There's a desktop program (JAVA) that allows for including subtitles in the downloads: https://mediathekview.de/

Comment: @bernhard-döbler, thanks very much. It works like a dream. If you write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as the best answer and hopefully that will help others in the future.

Comment: Do you fanatics even realise how stupid it looks to close a question like this one, when all I needed was one answer, which Bernhard Döbler has given already? You can close the question all you like, I've got what I needed - try taking that away. Couldn't care less what you do with the question now. Blinded by fanaticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a desktop program (requires JAVA runtime) that allows for downloading from the public TV stations' Mediatheks. It's possible to include subtitles in the downloads: mediathekview.de